# pthread_join() logical error using pthreads in c++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm learning pthreads in c++. I've stucked at some point and searched on the web, however the same sentence exists in all pages, however not any explanation about this sentence. I couldn't understand the below sentence.

**A joining thread can match one pthread_join() call. It is a logical error to attempt multiple joins on the same thread.**

It is from this link : http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreading_pthread.php

Could you explain what this sentence mean? Could you explain what the logical error is by an example?

What is "joining thread"? Say that, Main thread creates a child thread, main thread waits for child thread to complete its job. OK. in this case, which one is the joining thread , main thread or child thread?

Comment: Once a thread has been joined, it doesn't exist any more, so it would clearly be an error of trying to join the (now non-existing) thread again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if main() thread joins on a thread twice.

```
 pthread_t t1;

 pthread_create(&t1, ....);
 pthread_join(t1, NULL); 
 pthread_join(t1, NULL); /* The quoted sentence refers to cases like this */
```

The same is applicable for any other thread.

Comment: Ok. If more than one thread tries to join the same thread, what happens, is it ok?

Comment: It's *[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* to attempt to join more than once with the same thread. If you do so, the program is invalid henceforth.

Comment: @oiyio: You're the one who quoted, in the question, that it's a logical error. That's what your whole question is about. So, no, it's not ok!!

Comment: Then , the logical error mentioned in the question occurs  " if more than one thread tries to join the same thread". Am i right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not "more than one thread" but "more than once" by difference threads also. E.g. main() joins with thread1 and thread2 joins with thread1. This is invalid too.

Comment: Ok. I understand the concept. One last question, what is the joining thread  mentioned in sentence "joining thread can match one pthread_join() call" ? Say, main() joins with thread1. Which one is joining thread, main thread or thread1?

Comment: In the same article, it is mentioned about "target thread" also. Which one is "target thread"?

Comment: It's also thread1. Remember it's not necessary to call pthread_join() on every thread. It's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: you may only join a thread once.

```
                   main        worker 1
                     |
                     |
  pthread_create     +----------->+
                     |            |
                     |            |
  pthread_join       ⁞            |
        |            ⁞            | (done now)
        ┴            +<-----------+
                     |
                     |
                    (etc).
```

Comment: Say that, Main thread creates thread1 and thread2. 1 - Does it possible "main thread and thread2 simultaneously join thread2"?  2 - Does it possible "thread1 join thread2", in other words can a thread be joined by a thread which is not its parent?

Comment: @oiyio: The answer to both is in [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).